# Are matrix and array formulae in Excel multithreaded?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, multi-threaded

I know that Excel uses multithreading for calculation, but I could not find details about multithreading for matrix and array formulas, such as `MMULT`, `MAP`, `REDUCE` and the like.

I have two questions:

1. Does Excel calculate *different* array formulas simultaneously? (e.g. several columns, each of which is a separate array formula with many rows)
2. Does Excel ever use multiple threads to calculate a *single* array or matrix formula?

My experience suggests that the answers are:

1. yes,
2. no,

based on the fact that I can achieve close to 100% CPU utilization with about 10 independent large array formulas on a worksheet, but I haven't been able to go over 15% utilization with a single formula or several formulas dependent on each other.

The official documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/multithreading-and-memory-management) is silent on this topic, is there any other source of information or some way to verify how multithreading works with matrix and array formulas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/multithreaded-recalculation-in-excel) site, Excel calculates different formulas multi-threaded.

The page doesn't say anything about calculation of a single formula, so I suppose it always happens on one thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article and you can get the information about the Calculation process:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-improving-calculation-performance

Comment: The linked page does not answer the question.